# Assign keys to an array of objects

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following array: `[{id: 1, name: "john"}, {id: 2, name: "doe"}]`

How can I assign the id value of each object as a key and convert it to something like bellow ?

`[1:{id: 1, name: "john"}, 2:{id: 2, name: "doe"}]`

I did something like this `myArray.map((t) => {return {[t.id]: {t}}})` but obviously my result is nested in an object

Comment: *"something like below"*: well, that is not valid JavaScript notation. Did you mean an object instead of array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have specific properties (based on `id`), then the output should better be a plain object, and not an array.

In that case you can use `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
let data = [{id: 1, name: "john"}, {id: 2, name: "doe"}];
let result = Object.fromEntries(data.map(o => [o.id, o]));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You are totally right! Thanks for your help @trincot